# High RAM usage by NGINX

Tags: nginx

There are 6 NGINX processes in the server. Ever since NGINX is started, the RES/VIRT values kept growing until it is out of memory. Is it indicating there is a memory leak?

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1941  root      20   0  621m  17m 4144 S 290.4  0.1   8415:03 mongod
16383 nobody    20   0 1675m 1.6g  724 S 21.0  5.2  13:19.30 nginx
16382 nobody    20   0 1671m 1.6g  724 S 17.2  5.1  13:21.39 nginx
16381 nobody    20   0 1674m 1.6g  724 S 15.3  5.1  13:28.45 nginx
16380 nobody    20   0 1683m 1.6g  724 S 13.4  5.2  13:24.77 nginx
16384 nobody    20   0 1674m 1.6g  724 S 13.4  5.1  13:19.83 nginx
16385 nobody    20   0 1685m 1.6g  724 S 13.4  5.2  13:25.00 nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look on this [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) nginx module.

Also take a look to *client_max_body_size*